# In Objective C, are declared variables equal to nil?

Tags: objective-c, variables, nsmutablearray

I have a case where I'm declaring an NSMutableArray and then testing it like so:

```
-(void)whatever {
    NsMutableArray *array;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(array){
            [array release];
        }
        array = [[NsMutableArray alloc] init];
        // Add things to the array and do stuff with those things before starting over
    }
    if ([array count] > 0) {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

For some reason the `if(array){}` is evaluating to YES and it's trying to release an object that doesn't exist yet on the first pass through. It also evaluates to YES if I try `if(array != nil){}`. Is there a better way to test this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Objective-C, are int variables that haven't been assigned a value nil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114952/in-objective-c-are-int-variables-that-havent-been-assigned-a-value-nil)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are pointers always set to nil on declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071990/are-pointers-always-set-to-nil-on-declaration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare your `array` set it to nil:

```
NSMutableArray *array = nil;
```

Otherwise you can get junk in the pointer.

Comment: @levi: Also turn on the Clang static analyser fro builds.  It would have picked up this issue.

Answer (score 4):

The variable array is declared on the stack because it is declared in the function like that; it contains whatever was on the stack at that point, which for a lot of cases can be non NIL

You need to make sure to initialize the variable in that case, so you should use:

```
NSMutableArray *array = nil;
```

You should perform a `Product -> Analyze` for your code, which will detect a lot of common errors like this (as well as other errors).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this code, since the declared array will always be "nil" when you enter the loop. I'm assuming you have more stuff happening before, in which case you should do it like this instead:

```
-(void)whatever {
    NSMutableArray *array = nil;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(array){
            [array release];
            array = nil;
        }
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // Add things to the array and do stuff with those things before starting over
    }
    if ([array count] > 0) {
        // Do something else
    }   
}
```

When releasing an object (and you're SURE that its retain count will reach 0 and therefore it is actually deleted) then you should set `array` to nil, since even if the object is released, the `array` variable is just a pointer to the memory address where the object was located before it was deleted, and will not be nil.

Also, when declaring the variable, do `NSMutableArray *array = nil;` since otherwise it could just be any junk address on the stack, which will not evaluate to nil in your if-clause.